# Caption in landscape table, need help?

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

Today is my second day to learn making table in latex. I am facing the following difficulty.

I have a landscape table looks like the following

[image]

I would my table looks like the one in the Journal of Finance, I demonstrate one example,

[image]

So there are two things I need some helps with.

1. I want my table to span multiple pages, I tried `longtable`, but it does not really do what I want. Can anyone help me with that ??
2. For the caption, I would like the `Table 1:` also in bold and large,as the one I showed in the published paper. And I want my caption span the `textwidth`, but I do not know-how.
3. Which font the published paper used? If anyone can recognise it, can you change my font/font size to the one in the paper?

Thank you very much ! I am really struggling here. The following is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{makecell,graphicx,rotating,array,dcolumn,lscape,longtable,caption,lscape}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\def\sym#1{\ensuremath{^{\mathrlap{#1}}}}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTleft{-40pt}    
\setlength\LTright{-40pt}           
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \caption{\textbf{\large{The Results of Future Abnormal Return}}\\ This table reports the  This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the }
  \end{minipage}
    \begin{tabular}{ll*{8}{r@{}>{$}l<{$}}}
    \toprule
     \multicolumn{2}{l}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW1M}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW12M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW1M} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW12M}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}  &       \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(7)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(8)}\\ \midrule
       Purchaser (NPV) &&0.019&^{***}&0.021&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.017&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.038&^{***}&0.060&^{***}\\
          &&(36.58)&&(26.98)&&(23.34)&&(16.84)&&(34.03)&&(31.64)&&(34.72)&&(38.85)\\
         Count &&130,982  &&129,738    &&128,316    &&124,121    &&130,982        &&129,738    &&128,316    &&124,121\\
          Purchaser (NPR) &&0.019&^{***}&0.021&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.017&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.038&^{***}&0.060&^{***}\\
          &&(36.57)&&(26.99)&&(23.37)&&(16.89)&&(34.03)&&(31.64)&&(34.72)&&(38.85)\\
       Count   &&130,904  &&129,660    &&128,239    &&124,051    &&130,982        &&129,738    &&128,316    &&124,121\\ 
Seller (NPV)&& -0.007   & *** & -0.015   & *** & -0.020   & *** & -0.026   & *** & -0.003   & *** & -0.007   & *** & -0.009   & *** & -0.007  & *** \\               &  & (-27.13) &     & (-35.89) &     & (-34.16) &     & (-31.93) &     & (-13.05) &     & (-17.63) &     & (-15.62) &     & (-8.71) &     \\
Count        &  & 300,988  &     & 297,590  &     & 291,807  &     & 278,807  &     & 300,988  &     & 297,590  &     & 291,807  &     & 278,807 &     \\     
Seller (NPR) &  & -0.007   & *** & -0.015   & *** & -0.020   & *** & -0.026   & *** & -0.003   & *** & -0.007   & *** & -0.009   & *** & -0.007  & *** \\
             &  & (-27.16) &     & (-35.94) &     & (-34.19) &     & (-31.97) &     & (-13.08) &     & (-17.68) &     & (-15.65) &     & (-8.76) &     \\
Count        &  & 300,902  &     & 297,505  &     & 291,722  &     & 278,726  &     & 300,902  &     & 297,505  &     & 291,722  &     & 278,726 &     \\
Mom12=5      &  & -0.002   & *** & -0.005   & *** & -0.005   & *** & -0.015   & *** & 0.000    &     & 0.000    &     & 0.003    & *** & 0.001   &     \\
             &  & (-3.54)  &     & (-6.53)  &     & (-4.65)  &     & (-10.33) &     & (0.88)   &     & (-0.31)  &     & (2.42)   &     & (0.67)  &     \\
Count        &  & 102,749  &     & 101,378  &     & 99,148   &     & 94,324   &     & 102,749  &     & 101,378  &     & 99,148   &     & 94,324  &     \\
Mom12=1      &  & 0.002    & *** & -0.002   & *   & -0.001   &     & 0.005    & **  & 0.003    & *** & 0.005    & *** & 0.014    & *** & 0.038   & *** \\
             &  & (2.43)   &     & (-1.55)  &     & (-0.44)  &     & (2.19)   &     & (4.17)   &     & (3.67)   &     & (7.59)   &     & (14.87) &     \\
Count        &  & 57,001   &     & 56,326   &     & 55,230   &     & 52,905   &     & 57,001   &     & 56,326   &     & 55,230   &     & 52,905  &     \\
Mom24=5      &  & -0.002   & *** & -0.008   & *** & -0.010   & *** & -0.021   & *** & -0.001   &     & -0.004   & *** & -0.002   & **  & -0.003  & **  \\
             &  & (-4.52)  &     & (-10.34) &     & (-9.60)  &     & (-14.28) &     & (-1.11)  &     & (-4.67)  &     & (-2.30)  &     & (-2.08) &     \\
Count        &  & 100,870  &     & 99,492   &     & 97,333   &     & 92,652   &     & 100,870  &     & 99,492   &     & 97,333   &     & 92,652  &     \\
Mom24=1      &  & 0.005    & *** & 0.004    & *** & 0.001    &     & 0.001    &     & 0.007    & *** & 0.011    & *** & 0.014    & *** & 0.030   & *** \\
             &  & (5.64)   &     & (2.84)   &     & (0.55)   &     & (0.52)   &     & (7.74)   &     & (8.20)   &     & (7.47)   &     & (10.83) &     \\
Count        &  & 48,490   &     & 47,999   &     & 47,176   &     & 45,153   &     & 48,490   &     & 47,999   &     & 47,176   &     & 45,153  &     \\
Overall      &  & 0.001    & *** & -0.004   & *** & -0.006   & *** & -0.010   & *** & 0.003    & *** & 0.002    & *** & 0.005    & *** & 0.014   & *** \\
             &  & (2.32)   &     & (-11.57) &     & (-12.01) &     & (-14.03) &     & (11.82)  &     & (6.10)   &     & (10.12)  &     & (18.43) &     \\
Count        &  & 432,005  &     & 427,360  &     & 420,155  &     & 402,960  &     & 432,005  &     & 427,360  &     & 420,155  &     & 402,960 &\\ \bottomrule   
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Reference: Fama, E.F. & French, K.R. 2008, "Dissecting Anomalies", The Journal of Finance, vol. 63, no. 4, pp. 1653-1678

Comment: Your table is not only too tall for the landscape page but also too wide. Also, why are some of the asterisks in superscript while some aren't?

Comment: @leandriis Hi,leandriis. Thank you for your reply. Because today is my 2nd day to learn Latex, I have been spending hours online to "source" for a solution. So I wanted to do it by "trial-and-error" method. I might have loaded some useless stuff. Do not be bothered by asterisks, they are serving their purposes. It is significance level in short

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using the `longtable` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false, font={large, bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{array,lscape,longtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}

    \begin{longtable}{ll*{8}{r@{}>{$}l<{$}}}
      \caption{The Results of Future Abnormal Return}\label{tab:addlabel}\\ 
      \multicolumn{18}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}{This table reports the  This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the } \\
    \toprule
         \multicolumn{2}{l}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW1M}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW12M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW1M} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW12M}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}  &       \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(7)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(8)}\\ \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{\textbf{\large{The Results of Future Abnormal Return} - Continued}} \\
    \toprule
     \multicolumn{2}{l}{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW1M}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW12M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW1M} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW12M}\\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)}  &       \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(7)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(8)}\\ \midrule
      \endhead
       Purchaser (NPV) &&0.019&^{***}&0.021&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.017&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.038&^{***}&0.060&^{***}\\*
          &&(36.58)&&(26.98)&&(23.34)&&(16.84)&&(34.03)&&(31.64)&&(34.72)&&(38.85)\\*
         Count &&130,982  &&129,738    &&128,316    &&124,121    &&130,982        &&129,738    &&128,316    &&124,121\\  \addlinespace
          Purchaser (NPR) &&0.019&^{***}&0.021&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.017&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.038&^{***}&0.060&^{***}\\ 
          &&(36.57)&&(26.99)&&(23.37)&&(16.89)&&(34.03)&&(31.64)&&(34.72)&&(38.85)\\* 
       Count   &&130,904  &&129,660    &&128,239    &&124,051    &&130,982        &&129,738    &&128,316    &&124,121\\ \addlinespace 
Seller (NPV)&& -0.007   & ^{***} & -0.015   & ^{***} & -0.020   & ^{***} & -0.026   & ^{***} & -0.003   & ^{***} & -0.007   & ^{***} & -0.009   & ^{***} & -0.007  & ^{***} \\*               &  & (-27.13) &     & (-35.89) &     & (-34.16) &     & (-31.93) &     & (-13.05) &     & (-17.63) &     & (-15.62) &     & (-8.71) &     \\* 
Count        &  & 300,988  &     & 297,590  &     & 291,807  &     & 278,807  &     & 300,988  &     & 297,590  &     & 291,807  &     & 278,807 &     \\ \addlinespace   
Seller (NPR) &  & -0.007   & ^{***} & -0.015   & ^{***} & -0.020   & ^{***} & -0.026   & ^{***} & -0.003   & ^{***} & -0.007   & ^{***} & -0.009   & ^{***} & -0.007  & ^{***} \\ \addlinespace
             &  & (-27.16) &     & (-35.94) &     & (-34.19) &     & (-31.97) &     & (-13.08) &     & (-17.68) &     & (-15.65) &     & (-8.76) &     \\*
Count        &  & 300,902  &     & 297,505  &     & 291,722  &     & 278,726  &     & 300,902  &     & 297,505  &     & 291,722  &     & 278,726 &     \\  \addlinespace
Mom12=5      &  & -0.002   & ^{***} & -0.005   & ^{***} & -0.005   & ^{***} & -0.015   & ^{***} & 0.000    &     & 0.000    &     & 0.003    & ^{***} & 0.001   &     \\*
             &  & (-3.54)  &     & (-6.53)  &     & (-4.65)  &     & (-10.33) &     & (0.88)   &     & (-0.31)  &     & (2.42)   &     & (0.67)  &     \\* 
Count        &  & 102,749  &     & 101,378  &     & 99,148   &     & 94,324   &     & 102,749  &     & 101,378  &     & 99,148   &     & 94,324  &     \\ \addlinespace
Mom12=1      &  & 0.002    & ^{***} & -0.002   & *   & -0.001   &     & 0.005    & ^{**}  & 0.003    & ^{***} & 0.005    & ^{***} & 0.014    & ^{***} & 0.038   & ^{***} \\ 
             &  & (2.43)   &     & (-1.55)  &     & (-0.44)  &     & (2.19)   &     & (4.17)   &     & (3.67)   &     & (7.59)   &     & (14.87) &     \\*
Count        &  & 57,001   &     & 56,326   &     & 55,230   &     & 52,905   &     & 57,001   &     & 56,326   &     & 55,230   &     & 52,905  &     \\ \addlinespace
Mom24=5      &  & -0.002   & ^{***} & -0.008   & ^{***} & -0.010   & ^{***} & -0.021   & ^{***} & -0.001   &     & -0.004   & ^{***} & -0.002   & ^{**}  & -0.003  & ^{**}  \\*
             &  & (-4.52)  &     & (-10.34) &     & (-9.60)  &     & (-14.28) &     & (-1.11)  &     & (-4.67)  &     & (-2.30)  &     & (-2.08) &     \\* 
Count        &  & 100,870  &     & 99,492   &     & 97,333   &     & 92,652   &     & 100,870  &     & 99,492   &     & 97,333   &     & 92,652  &     \\ \addlinespace
Mom24=1      &  & 0.005    & ^{***} & 0.004    & ^{***} & 0.001    &     & 0.001    &     & 0.007    & ^{***} & 0.011    & ^{***} & 0.014    & ^{***} & 0.030   & ^{***} \\* 
             &  & (5.64)   &     & (2.84)   &     & (0.55)   &     & (0.52)   &     & (7.74)   &     & (8.20)   &     & (7.47)   &     & (10.83) &     \\*
Count        &  & 48,490   &     & 47,999   &     & 47,176   &     & 45,153   &     & 48,490   &     & 47,999   &     & 47,176   &     & 45,153  &     \\  \addlinespace
Overall      &  & 0.001    & ^{***} & -0.004   & ^{***} & -0.006   & ^{***} & -0.010   & ^{***} & 0.003    & ^{***} & 0.002    & ^{***} & 0.005    & ^{***} & 0.014   & ^{***} \\*
             &  & (2.32)   &     & (-11.57) &     & (-12.01) &     & (-14.03) &     & (11.82)  &     & (6.10)   &     & (10.12)  &     & (18.43) &     \\* 
Count        &  & 432,005  &     & 427,360  &     & 420,155  &     & 402,960  &     & 432,005  &     & 427,360  &     & 420,155  &     & 402,960 &\\ \bottomrule   
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Personally, I'd suggest the usage of either `dcolumn` or `siunitx` to align the numbers in the table columns. I have not changed that in the above example.

[image]

Comment: Yes Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much! And, if it is not too much trouble, can you demonstrate the usage of  `dcolumn`  in my case and not modify the code you have posted (post a separate code). !!!! Thanks again

Comment: @veryBigman: For an example on how to use the `dcolumn` package, you might want to have a look at [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500867/134144) to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference ! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6):

Some off-topic refinement of your table ...

With correct use of `\longtable`, `S` columns type defined in the `siunitx` package for numbers (and use only 9 columns, not 18 in your MWE), using your new command `\sym` for designating numbers in table with `*` (on more consistent way), added "Continue on the next page" at bottom of table parts (except the last one), ...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath} load and superset with mathtool
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[font={bf,small}]{caption}
% packages related to tables
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell,
%            dcolumn,
            longtable}
%\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\sym#1{\ensuremath{^{\mathrlap{#1}}}}
\usepackage{graphicx,
            rotating,
            pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{} l*{8}{ S[table-format=-3.5,
                               input-symbols={(-)},
                               parse-numbers=false]}
                  @{} }             
\caption{The Results of Future Abnormal Return}
\label{tab:addlabel}            \\

\multicolumn{9}{@{} p{\linewidth} @{}}{
This table reports the  This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the}   \\
    \toprule
    & {EW1M}  & {EW3M}  & {EW6M}  & {EW12M} & {VW1M}  & {VW3M}  & {VW6M}  & {VW12M} \\
    & {(1)}   &  {(2)}  & {(3)}   &  {(4)}  & {(5)}   & {(6)}   & {(7)}   & {(8)}   \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{The Results of Future Abnormal Return} \\
    \toprule
    & {EW1M}  & {EW3M}  & {EW6M}  & {EW12M} & {VW1M}  & {VW3M}  & {VW6M}  & {VW12M} \\
    & {(1)}   &  {(2)}  & {(3)}   &  {(4)}  & {(5)}   & {(6)}   & {(7)}   & {(8)}   \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{9}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape       
                        Continue on the next page}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% table body
Purchaser (NPV) 
    & 0.019\sym{***}    & 0.021\sym{***}    & 0.025\sym{***}    & 0.025\sym{***}
    & 0.01\sym{***}     & 0.025\sym{***}    & 0.038\sym{***}    & 0.060\sym{***}    \\
    & (36.58)           & (26.98)           & (23.34)           & (16.84)
    & (34.03)           & (31.64)           & (34.72)           & (38.85)           \\
Count 
    & 130,982           & 129,738           & 128,316           & 124,121    
    & 130,982           & 129,738           & 128,316           & 124,121           \\
Purchaser (NPR)
    & 0.019\sym{***}    & 0.021\sym{***}    & 0.025\sym{***}    & 0.025\sym{***}
    & 0.017\sym{***}    & 0.025\sym{***}    & 0.038\sym{***}    & 0.060\sym{***}    \\
    & (36.57)           & (26.99)           & (23.37)           & (16.89)    
    & (34.03)           & (31.64)           & (34.72)           & (38.85)           \\
Count   
    & 130,904           & 129,660           & 128,239           & 124,051   
    & 130,982           & 129,738           & 128,316           & 124,121           \\
Seller (NPV)
    & -0.007\sym{***}   & -0.015\sym{***}   & -0.020\sym{***}   & -0.026\sym{***}
    & -0.003\sym{***}   & -0.007\sym{***}   & -0.009\sym{***}   & -0.007\sym{***}   \\               & (-27.13)          & (-35.89)          & (-34.16)          & (-31.93)
    & (-13.05)          & (-17.63)          & (-15.62)          & (-8.71)           \\
Count        
    & 300,988           & 297,590           & 291,807           & 278,807  
    & 300,988           & 297,590           & 291,807           & 278,807           \\
Seller (NPR) 
    & -0.007\sym{***}   & -0.015\sym{***}   & -0.020\sym{***}   & -0.026\sym{***}
    & -0.003\sym{***}   & -0.007\sym{***}   & -0.009\sym{***}   & -0.007\sym{***}   \\
    & (-27.16)          & (-35.94)          & (-34.19)          & (-31.97) 
    & (-13.08)          & (-17.68)          & (-15.65)          & (-8.76)           \\
Count        
    & 300,902           & 297,505           & 291,722           & 278,726  
    & 300,902           & 297,505           & 291,722           & 278,726           \\
Mom12=5      
    & -0.002\sym{***}   & -0.005\sym{***}   & -0.005\sym{***}   & -0.015\sym{***}
    & 0.000             & 0.000             & 0.003\sym{***}    & 0.001             \\
    & (-3.54)           & (-6.53)           & (-4.65)           & (-10.33) 
    & (0.88)            & (-0.31)           & (2.42)            & (0.67)            \\
Count        
    & 102,749           & 101,378           & 99,148            & 94,324   
    & 102,749           & 101,378           & 99,148            & 94,324            \\
Mom12=1      
    & 0.002\sym{***}    & -0.002\sym{*}        & -0.001         & 0.005\sym{**}
    & 0.003\sym{***}    & 0.005\sym{***}    & 0.014\sym{***}    & 0.038\sym{***}    \\
    & (2.43)            & (-1.55)           & (-0.44)           & (2.19)  
    & (4.17)            & (3.67)            & (7.59)            & (14.87)           \\
Count        
    & 57,001            & 56,326            & 55,230            & 52,905  
    & 57,001            & 56,326            & 55,230            & 52,905            \\
Mom24=5      
    & -0.002\sym{***}   & -0.008\sym{***}   & -0.010\sym{***}   & -0.021\sym{***}
    & -0.001            & -0.004\sym{***}   & -0.002\sym{**}    & -0.003\sym{**}    \\
    & (-4.52)           & (-10.34)          & (-9.60)           & (-14.28) 
    & (-1.11)           & (-4.67)           & (-2.30)           & (-2.08)           \\
Count        
    & 100,870           & 99,492            & 97,333            & 92,652   
    & 100,870           & 99,492            & 97,333            & 92,652            \\
Mom24=1      
    & 0.005\sym{***}    & 0.004\sym{***}    & 0.001             & 0.001
    & 0.007\sym{***}    & 0.011\sym{***}    & 0.014\sym{***}    & 0.030\sym{***}    \\
    & (5.64)            & (2.84)            & (0.55)            & (0.52)   
    & (7.74)            & (8.20)            & (7.47)            & (10.83)           \\
Count        
    & 48,490            & 47,999            & 47,176            & 45,153  
    & 48,490            & 47,999            & 47,176            & 45,153            \\
Overall      
    & 0.001\sym{***}    & -0.004\sym{***}   & -0.006\sym{***}   & -0.010\sym{***}
    & 0.003\sym{***}    & 0.002\sym{***}    & 0.005\sym{***}    & 0.014\sym{***}    \\
   & (2.32)             & (-11.57)          & (-12.01)          & (-14.03)
   & (11.82)            & (6.10)            & (10.12)           & (18.43)           \\
Count        
    & 432,005           & 427,360           & 420,155           & 402,960  
    & 432,005           & 427,360           & 420,155           & 402,960           \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

note: it suffices to load each package only ones ...

Comment: Thanks! I will learn from it as much as i can. Thanks for your tine

Comment: you are welcome. see edited answer! and instead saying  "thanks", you can up-vote answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a variant with some improvements in the table layout, like  a spacing between groups of rows, and using the `xltabular`environment, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`. I also defined a more compact ‘three stars’ symbol (`\iiiast`).

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[labelfont={footnotesize, bf},textfont ={large, bf}, labelsep=newline, justification=centering]{caption}
    \usepackage{makecell, graphicx, rotating, dcolumn, lscape}
    \usepackage{xltabular}
    \newcommand{\iiiast}{\,{*}{*}{*}}

    \begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
    \def\sym#1{\ensuremath{^{\mathrlap{#1}}}}
    \begin{landscape}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2ex}
        \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth} {@{}X@{}*{8}{>{$}r<{$}@{}>{$}l<{$}}@{}}
     \caption{The Results of Future Abnormal Return \\[3ex] \parbox{\linewidth}{\normalfont\footnotesize This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the This table reports the }}
    \label{tab:addlabel} \\
     \toprule
     \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{17}{c}{\bfseries\footnotesize\tablename\,\thetable \textnormal{ (continued)}} \\[1ex]
     \toprule
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW1M}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{EW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{EW12M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW1M} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW3M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW6M}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{VW12M}\\
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(1)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2)} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(6)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(7)}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{(8)}\\ \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{17}{r@{}}{ \footnotesize(to be continued)}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
     Purchaser \rlap{(NPV)}
     &0.019&^{***}&0.021&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.017&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.038&^{***}&0.060&^{***} \\
     &(36.58)&&(26.98)&&(23.34)&&(16.84)&&(34.03)&&(31.64)&&(34.72)&&(38.85) \\
     Count &130,982 &&129,738 &&128,316 &&124,121 &&130,982 &&129,738 &&128,316 &&124,121 \\
     \addlinespace
     Purchaser \rlap{(NPR) } &0.019&^{***}&0.021&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.017&^{***}&0.025&^{***}&0.038&^{***}&0.060&^{***} \\
     &(36.57)&&(26.99)&&(23.37)&&(16.89)&&(34.03)&&(31.64)&&(34.72)&&(38.85) \\
     Count &130,904 &&129,660 &&128,239 &&124,051 &&130,982 &&129,738 &&128,316 &&124,121 \\
     \addlinespace
     Seller (NPV) & -0.007 & {*}{*}{*} & -0.015 & \iiiast & -0.020 & \iiiast & -0.026 & \iiiast & -0.003 & \iiiast & -0.007 & \iiiast & -0.009 & \iiiast & -0.007 & \iiiast \\
     & (-27.13) & & (-35.89) & & (-34.16) & & (-31.93) & & (-13.05) & & (-17.63) & & (-15.62) & & (-8.71) & \\
    Count & 300,988 & & 297,590 & & 291,807 & & 278,807 & & 300,988 & & 297,590 & & 291,807 & & 278,807 & \\
    \addlinespace
    Seller (NPR) & -0.007 & \iiiast & -0.015 & \iiiast & -0.020 & \iiiast & -0.026 & \iiiast & -0.003 & \iiiast & -0.007 & \iiiast & -0.009 & \iiiast & -0.007 & \iiiast \\
     & (-27.16) & & (-35.94) & & (-34.19) & & (-31.97) & & (-13.08) & & (-17.68) & & (-15.65) & & (-8.76) & \\
    Count & 300,902 & & 297,505 & & 291,722 & & 278,726 & & 300,902 & & 297,505 & & 291,722 & & 278,726 & \\
    \addlinespace
    Mom12=5 & -0.002 & \iiiast & -0.005 & \iiiast & -0.005 & \iiiast & -0.015 & \iiiast & 0.000 & & 0.000 & & 0.003 & \iiiast & 0.001 & \\
     & (-3.54) & & (-6.53) & & (-4.65) & & (-10.33) & & (0.88) & & (-0.31) & & (2.42) & & (0.67) \\
    Count & 102,749 & & 101,378 & & 99,148 & & 94,324 & & 102,749 & & 101,378 & & 99,148 & & 94,324 & \\
    \addlinespace
    Mom12=1 & 0.002 & \iiiast & -0.002 & * & -0.001 & & 0.005 & ** & 0.003 & \iiiast & 0.005 & \iiiast & 0.014 & \iiiast & 0.038 & \iiiast \\
     & (2.43) & & (-1.55) & & (-0.44) & & (2.19) & & (4.17) & & (3.67) & & (7.59) & & (14.87) & \\
    Count & 57,001 & & 56,326 & & 55,230 & & 52,905 & & 57,001 & & 56,326 & & 55,230 & & 52,905 & \\
    \addlinespace
    Mom24=5 & -0.002 & \iiiast & -0.008 & \iiiast & -0.010 & \iiiast & -0.021 & \iiiast & -0.001 & & -0.004 & \iiiast & -0.002 & ** & -0.003 & ** \\
     & (-4.52) & & (-10.34) & & (-9.60) & & (-14.28) & & (-1.11) & & (-4.67) & & (-2.30) & & (-2.08) & \\
    Count & 100,870 & & 99,492 & & 97,333 & & 92,652 & & 100,870 & & 99,492 & & 97,333 & & 92,652 & \\
    \addlinespace
    Mom24=1 & 0.005 & \iiiast & 0.004 & \iiiast & 0.001 & & 0.001 & & 0.007 & \iiiast & 0.011 & \iiiast & 0.014 & \iiiast & 0.030 & \iiiast \\
     & (5.64) & & (2.84) & & (0.55) & & (0.52) & & (7.74) & & (8.20) & & (7.47) & & (10.83) & \\
    Count & 48,490 & & 47,999 & & 47,176 & & 45,153 & & 48,490 & & 47,999 & & 47,176 & & 45,153 & \\
    \addlinespace
    Overall & 0.001 & \iiiast & -0.004 & \iiiast & -0.006 & \iiiast & -0.010 & \iiiast & 0.003 & \iiiast & 0.002 & \iiiast & 0.005 & \iiiast & 0.014 & \iiiast \\
     & (2.32) & & (-11.57) & & (-12.01) & & (-14.03) & & (11.82) & & (6.10) & & (10.12) & & (18.43) & \\
    Count & 432,005 & & 427,360 & & 420,155 & & 402,960 & & 432,005 & & 427,360 & & 420,155 & & 402,960 &
    \end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bernard. I went to bed yesterday. I am learning your method right now.

Comment: I learnt so much from your answer, this is very helpful! Let me express my gratitude again.